# AIR iOS app hangs when clicking button inside imported swf

Tags: actionscript-3, sdk, air, flash

Been bangin my head against a wall all day, thought I'd see if anyone can shed some light on this -

I have an iOS air app that imports a remote swf. Once imported, an event listener is added to a button inside the imported swf. Clicking the button causes the app to hang. Here's some code -

```
private function loadRemoteSWF():void{
    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.domain.com/remote.swf");

    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
    loader.load(urlRequest);
}

private function onLoaded(e:Event):void{
     var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = e.currentTarget as LoaderInfo;
     var adPanel:MovieClip = loaderInfo.content as MovieClip;

     adPanel.continueButton.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onContinueClicked);

     addChild(adPanel)
}

private function onContinueClicked(e:TouchEvent):void{
    trace("onContinueClicked");

}
```

I'm using Flash Builder 4.7 AIR SDK 3.5 ASC 2.0.

This only happens on a release build, debug builds work fine so near impossible to find the cause. It also works fine when using the legacy compiler on the same SDK version.

Dispatching a touch event programatically on the button also works fine. (thought I could do a try/catch to find an error)

```
adPanel.continueButton.dispatchEvent(new TouchEvent(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN));
```

Touching the button just kills the app, it doesn't even hit the trace.

Anyone got any ideas how to debug this, or why this problem might be happening?

Thanks
Dave

Comment: I'm sure that I've read (somewhere here on SO) that on iOS you can't load SWF and apply any actions (or execute action from loaded SWF). - maybe this is what you are experiencing. Also try [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713865/how-to-run-an-external-swf-inside-a-flex-application?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

can you do a test: instead of using the the native loader, try using an API, like greensocks api - SWFLoader.

Also, try setting the accepted domains through the security class prior to loading the swf file:

```
import flash.system.Security;

public class Main extends MovieClip{

    public function Main(){
       Security.allowDomain("*");
    }
}
```

I would suggest trying to compile with the same setup on a different machine, just to make sure that the Builder install doesn't have some issues.

Also, have you tried on different devices, (could be an issue with the device you are using)?